# setting javascript object properties from constructor default values using parameter destructuring

Tags: javascript, constructor, ecmascript-6, default, destructuring

This is a bit of a tricky question regarding ES6 destructuring with default usage in a javascript  object constructor.

I would like to receive a destructured parameters object with default values for my object constructor

so what i did was this

```
function bla({a=3,b=6}={}){
  this.a=a;
  this.b=b;
  console.log(`this.a::'${this.a}' this.b::'${this.b}' a::'${a}' b::'${b}'`);
}

let myObject= new bla({a:1});
console.log(`myObject.a::'${myObject.a}' myObject.b::'${myObject.b}'`); // only a got overriden with value "1" and b remained its defauly value "6"
```

I know that what i did works. However,  you can see that this is a bit of a code smell, because every time i need to add a new parameter to the constructor (for example {newParameter=3}) i also need to go down and add a matching line like this in the constructor body

```
this.newParameter=newParameter;
```

Is there any more elegant way to add a destructured parameter with default value which automatically is attached to "this."

Comment: One thing you can do is to give default values at the time of assignment e.g `this.a = a || 3`. So that you update only one line of code.

Comment: @AnuragSinghBisht: What if `a` is `0`? You lose the provided value.

Comment: @spanky You will need to update the condition as per your need. The point was to assign default values later on if you want to update only one line of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally think your current approach is the most readable, but you can technically also do

```
function bla(obj = {}){
  ({
    a: this.a = 3,
    b: this.b = 6,
  } = obj);

  console.log(`this.a::'${this.a}' this.b::'${this.b}'`);
}
```

Comment: But `this.a = 3` will not be executed if a value of `a` is passed, no?

Comment: Wow, never knew that this was valid syntax. JavaScript got weird since the last time I used it. Also, I think Felix has a good point.

Comment: @FelixKling I had a typo, but the `this.a` is the target of the destructure, just like if you did `{a: val} = obj`.

Comment: @AaditMShah I had to update my example FYI, I had a mistake in there. Essentially though `({foo} = obj);` is like `foo = obj.foo` and `({foo: bar} = obj);` is like `bar = obj.foo`, so `({a: this.a} = obj)` is just like `this.a = obj.a;`. Not very readable though.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this pearl. I took your example and [one-upped it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45775539/783743). You deserve an upvote.

Comment: Indeed mine is more readable. But i get the feeling that what you wrote will cause less defects down the road. Funny there is no existing native js funtion signature syntax to solve it with out doing tricks. Seems like there should be.... i smella new es2019 proposal? :)

Answer (score 0):

I follow more a functional style to avoid the `new` on object creation and `this` keyword.

### Explanation

You could simply write a function that retuns an `object` and takes several arguments with default values.
Thanks of the [object literal property value shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) you have less to write.

### Code

```js
function returnObject(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3) {
  return {
    a,
    b,
    c
  }
}

console.log(returnObject())
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is best, but you could use `Object.assign`.

```js
function bla(props={}) {
  Object.assign(this, {a:3,b:6}, props);
  console.log(`this.a::'${this.a}' this.b::'${this.b}'`);
}

let myObject= new bla({a:1});

console.log(`myObject.a::'${myObject.a}' myObject.b::'${myObject.b}'`); // only a got overriden with value "1" and b remained its defauly value "6"
```

You lose the parameter names, but it could be argued that this is better so that you don't accidentally mutate the parameter when you meant to mutate the object property.

Comment: Downside: this will add potential garbage properties to `this`.

Answer (score 0):

If the objective is to use the variable names exactly once then this is what I'd do:

```js
const foo = new Foo({ a: 1 });

console.log(`foo { a: ${foo.a}, b: ${foo.b} }`);

function Foo(config = {}) {
    const defaults = { a: 3, b: 6 };

    for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(defaults))
        ({ [key]: this[key] = val } = config);
}
```

Now, you only need to update the `defaults` object and you're done.

---

Actually, let's make a constructor constructor by abstracting this pattern:

```js
const Foo = defcons({ a: 3, b: 6 });

const foo = new Foo({ a: 1 });

console.log(`foo { a: ${foo.a}, b: ${foo.b} }`);

function defcons(defaults) {
    return function (config = {}) {
        for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(defaults))
            ({ [key]: this[key] = val } = config);
    };
}
```

Now, you can easily create as many such constructors as you want.